# Running an exe from with another exe C# and closing it

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to run an exe file inside another exe file in C#

That works well, however my problem is the exe that should run inside the other opens another console window, which I need to press "Enter" in, for it to stop after it has done what it does.

Is there a way to do that?

This is the code I have so far.

```
var proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "thefile.exe";
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
var exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
proc.Close();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just use cmd to open and terminat the exe / user window.

```
string executingCommand;
executingCommand= "/C Path\\To\\Your\\.exe";    // the /C terminates after carrying out the command
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", executingCommand);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are looking for the *input redirectioning*?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput(v=vs.110).aspx

```
  int exitCode = -1;

  // Put IDisposable into using
  using (var proc = new Process()) {
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "thefile.exe";
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

    proc.Start();

    using (StreamWriter inputWriter = proc.StandardInput) {
      inputWriter.Write('\n');
    }

    proc.WaitForExit();
    exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
  }
```